What is the error I have in my MARIE code for sorting an array?
I am trying to solve the following task:

Write an assembly code in MARIE to sort the following numbers (Hexadecimal) from maximum to minimum.
Numbers (HEX): 5, 35, 75, 45, 85, 25, 95, 55, 15, 65

You must store given values in the memory in the same order as given and as a hex value.
You must sort the values and store them in the same memory location where the original values are stored.
Your code should not ask any input value.


I tried to sort these numbers from least to greatest using the bubblesort algorithm.
This is my code:
ORG 1000    // Start of memory allocation

// Define variables
NUMBERS, HEX 5, 35, 75, 45, 85, 25, 95, 55, 15, 65
FLAG, DEC 0

// Constants
One, DEC 1

// Start of the program
Main,   Load NUMBERS     // Load the first number into AC
        Store 2000       // Store it in a temporary location for swapping
        Add One          // Move to next number
        Store X          // Store the address of the next number
Loop1,  Load X           // Load the next number into AC
        Skipcond 400     // If end of array is reached, exit the loop
        Jump EndLoop1    // Jump to end of outer loop if end of array is reached
        Load 2000        // Reload the first number into AC
        Subt X       // Compare the two numbers
        Skipcond 800     // If AC is greater than or equal to X, jump
        Jump Swap        // Jump to swap the numbers
        Jump Loop1       // Continue outer loop

Swap,   Load X           // Load the next number into AC
        Store 3000       // Store it in a temporary location
        Load 2000        // Load the first number into AC
        Store X          // Store it in the location of the next number
        Load 3000        // Load the next number from the temporary location
        Store 2000       // Store it in the location of the first number
        Store FLAG       // Set flag indicating a swap was made
        Jump Loop1       // Continue outer loop

EndLoop1, Load FLAG      // Load flag value
         Skipcond 400    // If flag is 0 (no swaps), exit outer loop
         Jump Main       // Otherwise, repeat outer loop

// End of program
Halt     // Halt the program

// Variables and constants allocation
X, DEC 0

I get an error on line 4:
NUMBERS, HEX 5, 35, 75, 45, 85, 25, 95, 55, 15, 65

I went through my code and I don’t really know where there could be any errors even with syntax.
I am using the MARIE simulator to run these instructions in my IDE, along with an online MARIE simulator as well just to make sure it is not a problem with my IDE.
Another issue I have with this is that my Assembly Listing tab is completely blank whenever I try to pull up the error with my code. The only thing that it says on my MARIE editor is that I have one error and does not even specify the line.
I narrowed it down to my attempt of making an array comprised of hexadecimals, which is line 4 in the code above. The online MARIE simulator I use, highlights the error on line 4 as well.
What am I doing wrong?

HEX only takes a single parameter.  You need a separate line to initialize each element of your array.

The MARIE.js.org simulator not only highlights the line with the error, but also presents this error message:

SyntaxError:L4 - Incorrect form.

And yes, it is an incorrect form. As already mentioned in comments, you need to use one line per number of your array, so instead of this:
NUMBERS, HEX 5, 35, 75, 45, 85, 25, 95, 55, 15, 65

Do this:
NUMBERS, HEX 5 
         HEX 35
         HEX 75
         HEX 45
         HEX 85
         HEX 25
         HEX 95
         HEX 55
         HEX 15
         HEX 65

Some other issues:

You write that you want to sort the values "from least to greatest", but please be aware that the task you quoted asks for the opposite ("from
maximum to minimum*")

Store 2000: On MARIE.js.org this statement triggers an assembly error: "Address 2000 out of bounds.". You should not need to hard-code addresses in instruction operands. Instead define variables in your data section, and use their names.

The online simulator at MARIE.js.org has trouble interpreting Halt    //. The double slash is confusing it. Note that comments are supposed to start with one slash only. Replacing that solves the problem.

Put all the data after your program. Currently you have spread some of the data (NUMBERS, FLAG, ONE) before the program, and some other (X) after the program.

The instruction Add One          // Move to next number doesn't do what the comment suggests. The accumulator has the value that was found in the array, not its address. So you are not adding one to the thing you intended. To get the address of your array, you could use the ADR  type specifier for the definition of X.

Once you have fixed the previous point, Load X doesn't load an array value, it loads the address. To load the value at that array address, use LoadI X. Same problem with Subt X. In the swapping algorithm you'll need it to, combined with StoreI.

You've got the interpretation of Skipcond 400 wrong: the code and comments suggest that you think the next statement will be executed when the accumulator is 0, but it is the opposite: the next statement will be skipped when that is the case.
Related, the comment "If AC is greater than or equal to X, jump" is wrong. The operand Skipcond 800 means "skip next statement when AC is greater than zero" (not equal!).

There is no place in your code where you reset the flag back to 0. When you get at EndLoop1, you need to reset the flag back to 0 before repeating the program.

You consider that the array is terminated by a zero, but that is the memory location for FLAG, and as you change its value at a swap, you thereby destroy that end-of-array marker, which would make your code read things that do not belong to the array.


Here is a fix of your code:
// Start of the program
Main,     Clear            / Clear the flag (to indicate that no swap was made so far)
          Store Flag       
          Load  NumbersAdr / Load the address of the first number into AC
          Store PrevAdr    / Store it in a temporary location for swapping
          Add One          / Move to next number
          Store CurrAdr    / Store the address of the next number
Loop1,    LoadI CurrAdr    / Load the next number into AC
          Skipcond 400     / If end of array is reached, exit the loop
          Jump Continue
          Jump EndLoop1    / Jump to end of outer loop if end of array is reached
Continue, Store Curr
          LoadI PrevAdr    / Compare the two numbers
          Subt  Curr
          Skipcond 000     / If previous value is less, swap (as we want to sort descending)
          Jump Step        / No swap needed, continue outer loop

Swap,     LoadI PrevAdr    / Load the lesser number into AC
          StoreI CurrAdr   
          Load  Curr
          StoreI PrevAdr
          Store Flag       / Set flag indicating a swap was made

Step,     Load CurrAdr
          Store PrevAdr
          Add One
          Store CurrAdr
          Jump Loop1       / Continue outer loop

EndLoop1, Load Flag        / Load flag value
          Skipcond 400     / If flag is 0 (no swaps), exit outer loop
          Jump Main        

          / End of program
          Halt     / Halt the program

/ Variables
CurrAdr, DEC 0 / Pointer that traverses the array
PrevAdr, DEC 0 / Pointer that follows one step behind
Curr,    DEC 0 / Temporary copy of the current value
Flag,    DEC 0 / Flag indicating whether last traversal made a swap
/ Array to sort
Numbers, HEX 5 
         HEX 35
         HEX 75
         HEX 45
         HEX 85
         HEX 25
         HEX 95
         HEX 55
         HEX 15
         HEX 65
/ Constants
Terminator, DEC 0  / To mark end of the array (Must be constant!)
One, DEC 1
NumbersAdr, ADR Numbers / Pointer to the start of the array

You can assemble and run it online on MARIE.js.org.
Running this code will give this memory snapshot:

This is a screenshot from the online simulator, where I highlighted the location of the (sorted) array with an orange border.

Any feedback, @TylerChetty? Did this help you out?
